# Elixir syntax error: Invalid token error when creating map

Tags: elixir

When I attempt to create a Map using the `%{}` syntax, Elixir reports a Syntax Error and fails. `map = %{foo: "bar", hello: "world"}` doesn't work. `map = %{:a => 1, 2 => :b}` (taken directly from the tutorial) doesn't work.

This problem happens in the Interactive environment:

```erlang
Erlang R16B03-1 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (0.12.5) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> %{2 => :b, :a => 1}
** (SyntaxError) iex:1: invalid token: %{2 => :b, :a => 1}
iex(1)> map = %{foo: "bar", hello: "world"}
** (SyntaxError) iex:1: invalid token: %{foo: "bar", hello: "world"}
iex(1)>
```

And also when running a script:

```erlang
$ cat simple.exs
map = %{:a => 1, 2 => :b}

$ elixir simple.exs
** (SyntaxError) simple.exs:1: invalid token: %{:a => 1, 2 => :b}
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:301: Code.require_file/2
```

On a (probably unrelated) note, the `i` command doesn't work either:

```erlang
iex(1)> i {1,2}
** (RuntimeError) undefined function: i/1
```

Is my Elixir installation messed up? This is on CentOS, installed using `yum install elixir`.

Comment: I was trying to find docs for that Elixir version but couldn't. It seems really old, as well as your Erlang version. Perhaps you could try installing more recent versions with kiex and kerl or with asdf?

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: @sbacaro I installed them using asdf and it's working fine now. The main problem was that I had installed elixir using `yum install elixir` and this gave me the old version. If you'd like, you can make your comment an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: @sbacaro `Erlang R16` did not have _maps_, so it is even not about _elixir_ version.

Comment: Elixir forum thread from a couple of years ago stating nobody is maintaining the centos packages: https://elixirforum.com/t/state-of-elixir-packages-on-centos-7/17365

Comment: Thanks @nbura, but I think it's fine to just close the question. I suspected it had to do with the versions, but the comments by @AlekseiMatiushkin and `@AdamMillerchip` provide more insight into why this actually happened.

Comment: The version 0.12.5 is from 2014. The latest package on CentOS seems to be that package

Answer (score 0):

The issue, in my case, was that I was using a very old version of Elixir/Erlang. The CentOS `yum` packages for Elixir are NOT kept up-to-date.

I uninstalled this version of Elixir and instead installed the most recent versions of Erlang and Elixir using `asdf`.

https://thinkingelixir.com/install-elixir-using-asdf/

https://gist.github.com/rubencaro/6a28138a40e629b06470